# Find which points are within a given distance of each point

Tags: r, distance, lapply, euclidean-distance

I have a dataframe that has a list of places and their geographical locations in UTM (Universal Transverse Mercator) coordinates.

It looks something like this:

```
Place    X_UTM   Y_UTM
    1 574262.0 6140492
    2 571251.2 6141669
    3 570841.9 6142535
    4 570233.8 6141213
    5 578269.2 6140304
    6 575067.1 6137444
```

I want to identify, for each Place (each row of the dataframe), which of the other places are within a given Euclidean distance. In this case, I want to find which places are closer than 1 kilometer.

I've tried something like this:

```
foo <- function(x, y) dist(c(x, y), method = "euclidian") < 1000
```

which should be a function that returns the points that are closer than 1000 meters. Then:

```
x <- lapply(df(,c(i, x, y)), FUN = foo)
```

where `i` is `"Place"`, `x` is `"X_UTM"` and `y` is `"Y_UTM"`. This do not work at all.

The output I am after should look something like this (not obtained from the numbers given above):

```
# Place Closest
#     1    2, 5
#     2       1
#     3      NA
#     4       5
#     5    1, 4
#     6      NA
```

Comment: Correct me if I be incorrect, but shouldn't your distance function accept two _points_, i.e. two x and two y values?

Comment: Yes. I want to calculate the distance between each row. That should be sqr((X_UTM[1] - X_UTM[i])^2 - (Y_UTM[1] - Y_UTM[i])^2) for all rows, then recording which [i] are less than 1000.

Comment: can you not do `dst <- as.matrix(dist(d[-1])) ;
diag(dst) <- NA ; 
apply(dst, 1, function(x) paste(which(x < 1000), collapse=", "))`

Comment: @user20650 works like a charm! Excellent answer. Just add as.data.frame to the result of apply. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome Leandro: you may prefer `stack` than `as.data.frame`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `sp::spDists` to return a distance matrix, and then find the elements of each column/row that meet your condition.

For example:

```
d <- read.table(text='Place   X_UTM        Y_UTM
1       574261.98   6140492.13
2       571251.23   6141669.26
3       570841.92   6142534.86
4       570233.75   6141212.5
5       578269.25   6140303.78
6       575067.07   6137444.36', header=TRUE)
```

```
library(sp) 
i <- apply(spDists(as.matrix(d[, c('X_UTM', 'Y_UTM')])), 2, 
           function(x) paste(which(x < 1000 & x != 0), collapse=', '))

data.frame(Place=d$Place, Closest=i)

##   Place Closest
## 1     1        
## 2     2       3
## 3     3       2
## 4     4        
## 5     5        
## 6     6
```

Comment: work perfectly. Just to add that spDist is in package sp. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `dist` will also work fine, as [pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38246575/how-to-find-the-elements-of-a-vector-wich-distance-is-less-than-a-value-in-r/38257822?noredirect=1#comment63915843_38246575) by @user20650. Also, my answer would fail to return any coincidental points - that is, any points with a distance of zero will be ignored. A better way to ignore "self" is to set the diagonal to `NA` as mentioned in user20650's comment.

Comment: Very nice, but is there a way to visual these clusters?

Comment: Actually it is not working correctly for me. Points that are within the distance are not marked. Is this considering within a radius or just the horizontal distance?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to need to *cross join* the Place coordinates.  The reason for this is that any pair of Places could be nearest neighbors, and assuming you don't have any a priori information which could rule out certain pairs, you need to check all of them.

One way of getting the cross join of your data frame `df` is to merge it with itself, setting `by = NULL` as a parameter into `merge`:

```
df.cross <- merge(x = df, y = df, by = NULL)
df.cross$distance <- apply(df.cross[, c('X_UTM.x', 'X_UTM.y', 'Y_UTM.x', 'Y_UTM.y')],
      1,
      function(x) dist(x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]))
```

Now all you need to do is find the minimum distance for each pair of places.

Comment: Dear @Tim Biegeleisen, thanks for your answer. I have the following when running the script you kindly share:  Error in dist(x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]) : invalid distance method

Comment: You need to redefine your `dist` function to take two x values and two values, for two Cartesian points.